# Can we add a back feature to a do while menu selector in java?

Tags: java, menu, back

So I was working on a project for university, and I decided to use the classic do-while loop with a switch case in it to make a selector menu, but I want it instead of it asking the user for another case immediately after performing one, I want kind of like a back menu button, I searched the web but couldn't find a similar question to mine.

I included my code down below, so for example if I chose case 1, it will print "case 1" and then reprint the menu, but I want it to hold until the user enter an input then it will loop to the menu again.
Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean repeat = true;
      int operator;
      do {
         System.out.println("1 - menu");
         System.out.println("2 - menu");
         System.out.println("3 - menu");
         System.out.println("4 - menu");
         System.out.println("5 - menu");
         System.out.println("Enter the Menu Number you want to Enter: ");
         operator = input.nextInt();
         switch (operator) {
            case 1:
               System.out.println("case 1");
               break;
               

            case 2:
               System.out.println("case 2");
               break;
            
            case 3:
               System.out.println("case 3");
               break;

            case 4:
               System.out.println("case 4");
               break;
               
            case 5:
               System.out.println("Exiting in process...");
               System.exit(0);
               break;
         
            default:
            System.out.println(operator + " is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another.");
               break;
         }
      } while (operator != 5);
      input.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hold"? What do you want it to wait for?

Comment: @FairOPShotgun What i mean that i want that i don't want the selector menu to directly show up after the previous selected case is done i want the user to enter a string or something then it will break the case and loop

Comment: Please see my answer and decide if that is what you want. Also, please use proper punctuation and grammar because it makes it easier for me to understand. I don't understand your question and I ask you to edit your comment above to state the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// Import java.util for TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Main {
  // Create the wait function 
  public static void wait(int ms){
    try {
      Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean repeat = true;
      int operator;
       do {
         System.out.println("1 - menu");
         System.out.println("2 - menu");
         System.out.println("3 - menu");
         System.out.println("4 - menu");
         System.out.println("5 - menu");
         System.out.println("Enter the Menu Number you want to Enter: ");
         operator = input.nextInt();
         switch (operator) {
        case 1:
           System.out.println("case 1");
           /** Add wait(3000); to every line! This will allow 
         the code to hold 3 seconds before returning back to the menu**/ 
           wait(3000);
           break;
           
        case 2:
           System.out.println("case 2");
           wait(3000);
           break;
        
        case 3:
           System.out.println("case 3");
           wait(3000);
           break;

        case 4:
           System.out.println("case 4");
           wait(3000);
           break;
           
        case 5:
           System.out.println("Exiting in process...");
           wait(1000);
           System.exit(0);
           break;
     
        default:
           System.out.println(operator + " is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another.");
           wait(3000);
           break;
     }
  } while (operator != 5);
  input.close();
   }
}
```

I used a TimeUnit util to create a wait function. This wait function works as:

```
wait(int ms)
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, it's a good idea for my program, not exactly what I wanted but I figured out how to do what I want just now, I just add a line of code to something only then it will continue my code and break the case and return to the menu, and sorry for not describing exactly what I want, English isn't my first language but I try my best so yeah. Thank you again.